# Draw circular shape with overlapping border

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I draw this kind of ellipse

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that we are all spending our precious free time to help each other here. Therefore, we'd like it if a question shows about the same amount of effort as a good answer to the question would. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I can assure you that I have tried. Someone told me that I can achieve something similar to this this by drawing 2 ellipse and making one a bit smaller. I tried, but the result wasn't anything like this.
Besides, the main problem here is that I can't think of any "approach" that will give me something like this. And thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Even if your attempts turned out not to work, please *do* post them--it shows us that you actually tried, instead of coming here and besically saying 'please make me this'. We've had a tad bit too much askers like that, recently :/ Thanks!

Comment: I understand. And thanks for the advice. Will keep taht in mind :)

Answer (score 7):

First to start its not an eclipse its a circle.

- Draw a perfect circle by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>:

[image]

- Draw an inner circle with the same approach as previous step:

[image]

- Go to `align` and center circles:

[image]

- Fill the outer circle with black and the inner circle with white:

[image]

- Select both circles and go to `Object -> CompoundPath -> Make` or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.
- Add a guide in the middle of the circle:

[image]

- Draw a shape across the circle:

[image]

- Select both and go to `pathfinder` and choose `Minus Front`:

[image]

- Create an ellipse with the `Ellipse Tool` and rotate it:

[image]

- Select the rotated oval and go to `Object -> Expand`:

[image]

- Select both and go to `pathfinder` and click `minus front`:

[image]

Copy and rotate:

[image]

You will need to play with the eclipse and rotation but you should get the general idea now.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar design before and I was able to do so in Illustrator using the Pencil tool and then adjusting the anchor points. Maybe there is a more technically savvy way to create this, but I normally just do so by trial-and-error.

Comment: Well, I am sure that this can be done with pen tool. But I find it very difficult to draw good circular shape with pen tool. So I am looking for some "savvy" solution for this :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Mate, I just created 3 circles, one large around the circumference - then two slightly smaller, centered horizontally and lined up so that they touch the center diameter. Cut the lines up and make compound shapes, filling with gradients. Place the logo image on a layer in Illustrator and trace over it with circles. People just don't try anymore